# How to configure Array on DL360 GEN 8 Server Running Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, raid, hp

Hi all I have an DL360 GEN 8 Machine. And I need to install ubuntu server on it. However. Accourding to HP, THE Dyanamic Smart Array System is not support. Since I would love to make use of array.. Given that I have 4 Terra bytes of disk .. Which I need to configure Raid 1.

> Blockquote

Is there any possible way to achive this Raid without HP Dynamic Array system. ???

> Blockquote

Below is the message from HP. Which says that I need to disable Smart array before I can be able to run Ubuntu

> HP Dynamic Smart Array System is certified with Dynamic Smart Array disabled. To disable Dynamic Smart Array:
>
> - Press F9 to boot into RBSU
> - Navigate to System Options > HP Dynamic Smart Array B320i and select disable
> - Go to System options > SATA Controller options and select Legacy SATA or AHCI
> - Reboot the machine and now you will be able to install the OS

Comment: I am looking for a way to use software raid instead of HP hardware Raid! This is the point I am making!

Comment: Okay. What's the problem? If you disable the hardware RAID, you then have to use software RAID. You'd configure that in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't use Ubuntu!!**

Use a Linux distribution that's [actually supported for this hardware](https://serverfault.com/a/526227/13325)!

> The HP Dynamic Smart Array B110i/B120i/B320i controller driver for
>   Ubuntu 12.04 is not available. The Ubuntu 12.04 certification was
>   completed in SATA mode.

See:

[Poor SQL performance on HP ProLiant ML310e Gen8 v2 with raid10](https://serverfault.com/questions/568313/poor-sql-performance-on-hp-proliant-ml310e-gen8-v2-with-raid10/568388#568388)

[HP ProLiant DL380e Gen8 server - SPP use](https://serverfault.com/questions/565221/hp-proliant-dl380e-gen8-server-spp-use/565224#565224)

[Install Oracle Linux 6.4 on HP ProLiant DL380e Gen8 server](https://serverfault.com/questions/562574/install-oracle-linux-6-4-on-hp-proliant-dl380e-gen8-server/562576#562576)

[Installing Ubuntu 12.04 on HP Proliant DL380e with 1TB SAS Drive](https://serverfault.com/questions/526111/installing-ubuntu-12-04-on-hp-proliant-dl380e-with-1tb-sas-drive/526227#526227)

[Oracle Enterprise Linux installation can't see local disks on HP ProLiant DL360e Gen8](https://serverfault.com/questions/494740/oracle-enterprise-linux-installation-cant-see-local-disks-on-hp-proliant-dl360e/494754#494754)

Comment: He doesn't say which version of Ubuntu he's using, but based on [this](http://h17007.www1.hp.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/supportmatrix/ubuntu.aspx), both LTS 14.04 and LTS 12.04 are supported on the DL360 Gen8's.

Comment: @GregL The Ubuntu certification was completed without using the RAID controller. There's no array driver for the RAID controller for Ubuntu. So technically, the system can run Ubuntu if you disable all hardware RAID functionality. I'd deem that as _"unsupported"_ and definitely not ideal.

Comment: Right.. It does seem a little strange that one would buy a shiny new server and then throw out the RAID controller. That said, if he's running LTS 14.04 then he's fine. Presumably he's now however, or else he wouldn't be in this predicament. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @GegL Thanks for the insite. So crazy, one invest losts of money on a new system. with hard disk and ram. And have to learn the hard way, that the system will not do what its is meant to do. And reading a thread that says that a desktop may run faster than this most expensive server. does not make me feel happy either. I am thinking of moving to Red Hat Linux which is natively supported. And just pray that no issues comes up again

Comment: It's an Ubuntu problem. I don't think Ubuntu places a priority on hardware support, whereas some of the other commercial distributions (RHEL, SuSE) *do* have an emphasis on working with hardware vendors for support. CentOS works just fine on this hardware, too.

Comment: @ewwhite I have not use centOS it seems it might give almost all the features of Ubuntu.. I am looking to run a small e-Library application on it .. Just need Apache , MySql, and PHP. I am down on my knee with this hardware issues at the last moment. Will CentOS do the Job?

Comment: Yes, CentOS will work the same as Red Hat. You have to load a Driver Disk  when you run the installation in order to properly configure the Smart Array controller.