# Installing Ubuntu 12.04 on HP Proliant DL380e with 1TB SAS Drive

Tags: ubuntu, raid, hp, hp-proliant, sas

I have an HP Proliant DL380e with a 1TB SAS Drive and I am trying to
install ubuntu server 12.04 on it.

I have created a RAID array using Array Controller Utility and had a RAID0 logical
volume configured on that array. I also set this logical volume as the 
primary bootable device.

Having done this, I believe installing ubuntu on the created partition 
should be as smooth as it can be. However, it seems I am so wrong...

During the installation process, the installer does not detect my SAS
Drive. At the step required to partition disks, it only avails the option
to "Configure iSCSI Volumes".

When I checked the /var/log/syslog file. I see that the installer tries to 
detect SATA Drives but finds none.

Are there any custom configurations I need to make to get the installer to
successfully detect my SAS Drive? I can't quite figure out what I need 
to do get the installer to detect my SAS Drive.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show screenshots?

Comment: How can I take such screenshots during installation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Some models of the [HP ProLiant DL380e](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/quickspecs/productbulletin.html#spectype=north_america&type=html&docid=14328) use a [Dynamic Smart Array controller](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/proliantstorage/arraycontrollers/dynamicsmartarray/index.html). This is a low-end controller and doesn't have the same widespread support as a proper Smart Array controller. The other problem here is Ubuntu... Windows, Red Hat and SuSE all have drivers for this controller. Ubuntu does not. See the [**HP/Ubuntu technical exceptions matrix**](http://h18004.www1.hp.com/products/servers/linux/supportmatrix/ubuntu/exceptions/ubuntu-exceptions.html#DL).

> The HP Dynamic Smart Array B110i/B120i/B320i controller driver for
>   Ubuntu 12.04 is not available. The Ubuntu 12.04 certification was
>   completed in SATA mode.

Ubuntu is certified for the ProLiant DL380e *only* if the Dynamic Smart Array controller is disabled. [**Please see the Ubuntu certification notes**](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201203-10850/).

> System is certified with Dynamic Smart Array
>   disabled. To disable: *Press F9 to boot into RBSU *Navigate to System
>   Options -> HP Dynamic Smart Array B320i and select disable *Go to
>   System options -> SATA Controller options and select Legacy SATA or
>   AHCI *Reboot the machine and now you will be able to install the OS.

It's unfortunate. The DL380e is an entry-level server. The DL380p would work properly with no modification. But the other issue is that Ubuntu doesn't have the support for the RAID controller.

Comment: That worked. I will have to do away with RAID Support for now. Thank you.

Comment: Or *not* use Ubuntu? Maybe?

Comment: I'm looking at using something open source. FreeBSD, Open-SUSE, Archlinux all behaved the same. May be i'll purchase Red-hat or SUSE later. Thanks for now.

Comment: CentOS is compatible...

Comment: I have another ML310e G8 with the same issue, it has a 120i RAID Controller. I will try installing CentOS on it.