# Install Oracle Linux 6.4 on HP ProLiant DL380e Gen8 server

Tags: hp, oracle, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, fakeraid

installation does not detect the raid 1 logical drive created from ACU.
the installation shows the two 2T disks, and after the installation is complete, I can not boot up to the system.

I have been searching, and I am looking for the right procedure.

Do i need to an extra driver for smart array ? if yes which one and how to install it!

PS : on ILO interface within Storage section i have the message below : 
No Smart Array Controller found. 
HP Smart Array Controller or HP Dynamic Smart Array RAID Controller is required to display drive array information.

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

Continuing my search for full correct installation procedure, kindly check and advise about the procedure below. If i am missing any important detail

1. Download RHEL 6.4 Software Driver Update and extract it.
2. Copy hpvsa-1.2.4-4.rhel6uX.x86_64.dd to a USB Key formatted as
   FAT32.
3. Once the floppy driver diskette ready on the USB Key and the Array
   is being created, is time to begin the EL 6.4 installation by booting
   from the DVD.
4. On the main installation menu for EL, mount the USB Key with
   the driver on it. At the installation menu, select the installation method and hit “ESC” key to receive the "boot:" prompt
5. At that "boot" prompt enter the following command: 
   linux dd blacklist=ahci
6. Hit ENTER Select Yes for driver diskette, Select the USB drive.
7. Select the driver disk image and select OK .
8. Continue the OS installation, then just click select the logical
   volume where to install the EL (version 6.4).

---

Installation tested and works as expected.

Comment: Good. Please mark an answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I blame HP for convincing people to buy the **ProLiant DL360e/DL380e** series of servers. The storage controller is a big compromise on those servers. Here, you basically installed onto *one* of the two disks.

The HP Dynamic Smart Array needs a binary driver to really function... [See this Red Hat knowledge base article.](https://access.redhat.com/site/articles/118133) You'll have to slipstream it into the installation.

In order to install onto your server model, you'll require a driver disk for use during the installation process. The driver you need is the `hp-vsa` module. The install will need to be performed with a USB key.

**[Here's the link to the driver.](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=5293148&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=idx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_8950c5d266d34b3ba24f317c32%257CswEnvOID%253D4103%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken)** Choose the right binary driver for your EL version (6.4)

[**Here are the installation instructions**](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=5293148&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState%3Didx%253D2%257CswItem%253DMTX_8950c5d266d34b3ba24f317c32%257CswEnvOID%253D4103%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D4%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken).

Comment: Could you please advise, i updated the post.

Comment: @L1opardo Did this work for you?

Comment: Hi ewwhite : not yet, I will be installing this next week. My problem is that i dont have a test machine, i need to deploy this on production directly. So finger crossed.

Comment: Hi Ewwhite, one question please : 
When inserting the extra driver, from a process matter of view. the installation checks the driver to the current hardware ? and does rejects if the hardware is not compatible ?
Or it installs the driver anyway!

Answer (score 1):

The ilo can't display drive information if you don't have the raid tools suite installed on the machine, so that doesn't mean anything.

I'd boot to the controller interface, and make sure the array is configured correctly.