# HP ProLiant DL380e Gen8 server - SPP use

Tags: linux, redhat, hp, hp-proliant

I am planning to install Oracle Linux 6.4 on an HP ProLiant DL380e Gen8 server. I have been advised to use Service Pack for Proliant SSP DVD to install/update the missing utilities drivers for Oracle Linux 6.4.

Should I:

1. boot from the DVD?
2. install manually once the OS is installed?

Comment: Which RAID controller do you have installed in the system? How do you plan to configure storage?

Comment: Raid controller is B120i for SATA disks, storage configuration via ACU

Comment: Okay. Then create your array in the Intelligent Provisioning screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a number of options available to you for preparing a new, modern ProLiant Gen8 server for use. My approach varies depending on the operating system.

For your server, please answer my question about RAID configuration and the type of controller in the server.

- Boot the system and press <kbd>F10</kbd> for [Intelligent Provisioning](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/server-software/product-detail.html?oid=5219984#!tab=features).
- Configure your ILO and optionally basic network configuration parameters (*if the server isn't getting DHCP information*).
- Run the Firmware Update utility to download and install the current firmware revisions directly from HP (*assuming you have internet access from your location*).
- Create your array in the Intelligent Provisioning screen using the HP Array Configuration Utility (aka [HP Smart Storage Administrator](http://h30507.www3.hp.com/t5/Coffee-Coaching-HP-and-Microsoft/Introducing-HP-Smart-Storage-Administrator-for-ProLiant-Gen8/ba-p/147053)).
- Install your Linux OS. Oracle is Redhat-like, so I'll give the instructions for RHEL-derivatives.
- Following your OS installation, leverage the [HP SDR repository](http://downloads.linux.hp.com) and install the relevant packages for the system via yum.
- You'll need to install the following: "hp-snmp-agents", "hpssa", "hp-health", "hp-smh-templates", "hpsmh", "hpssacli", "hponcfg" - You may also need another package for the Dynamic Smart Array controller in the server.

Edit:

Your server has a Dynamic Smart Array RAID controller. It may not boot off of the array into the Oracle Linux installer without some assistance. [I answered this question earlier about driver disks](https://serverfault.com/questions/562574/install-oracle-linux-6-4-on-hp-proliant-dl380e-gen8-server/562576#562576).

Do the above and get your OS loaded. Following the OS installation, you will want to mount your SPP DVD and try to initiate an `hpsum` installation directly from the disk.

You can also just install the [Oracle MCP package for ProLiant](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=5269386&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState=idx%253D%257CswItem%253DMTX_be39dbe787b24c40b8973e5b6c%257CswEnvOID%253D4119%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) if you can download this bundle to the server.

Comment: thanks ewwhite, bare in mind i dont have internet access to the server. SDR use wouldn't be an option.
the use of hpsum within the SSP dvd is ? or as mentioned below http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=5269386&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState%3Didx%253D2%257CswItem%253DMTX_be39dbe787b24c40b8973e5b6c%257CswEnvOID%253D4118%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D4%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken
kindly advise!

Comment: This server won't have *any* internet access? Via proxy or otherwise?

Comment: No internet access in my current setup unfortunately :/

Comment: Well, that limits your options... One moment. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @L1opardo [Here are the installation instructions](http://h20566.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=5269386&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState%3Didx%253D2%257CswItem%253DMTX_be39dbe787b24c40b8973e5b6c%257CswEnvOID%253D4119%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D4%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken) for the 90mb Oracle package you need for agents after your OS has been installed. You don't need the DVD.

Comment: the MCP Package would do the trick, Again thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Booting from the DVD will take care of all firmware updates that are applicable to your system, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: What about the linux utilities, example for hp-snmp-agents, hpacucli
Do you recommend doing this via hpsum included within the SSP DVD or the link below that i found for OL6.4 http://h20565.www2.hp.com/portal/site/hpsc/template.PAGE/public/psi/swdDetails/?sp4ts.oid=5269386&spf_p.tpst=swdMain&spf_p.prp_swdMain=wsrp-navigationalState%3Didx%253D2%257CswItem%253DMTX_be39dbe787b24c40b8973e5b6c%257CswEnvOID%253D4118%257CitemLocale%253D%257CswLang%253D%257Cmode%253D4%257Caction%253DdriverDocument&javax.portlet.begCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken&javax.portlet.endCacheTok=com.vignette.cachetoken

Comment: I would use whichever is the latest version. If the SSP DVD has the same version of the utilities that are on the HP site, then just use the DVD. If not, pull the latest off of the HP site.