# How can I get the HP System Management Homepage to display more than "No items" on Linux?

Tags: centos, centos7, hp-proliant

After installing the HP System Management Homepage on Linux and logging on to the website, I get this displayed:

[image: HP SMH page showing "No items"]

The "Component Status Summary", "No items" isn't what I hope to see. The basic info like system model and management processor also suggest that it's not getting the information it needs.

## Environment

- Hardware: HPE DL360 G6
- Firmware: Oct 2016 (final release for DL360 G6)
- OS: CentOS 7.4
- SPP: Oct 2016 (to match above firmware)

## What I've tried

The basic installation was done following the general advice here:

http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/sdr/project/spp/

Here's how the SPP yum repo was configured (/etc/yum.repos.d/spp.repo):

```
[spp]
name=Service Pack for ProLiant
baseurl=http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/repo/spp/rhel/7Server/x86_64/2016.10.0/
enabled=0
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/GPG-KEY-ServicePackforProLiant
```

The GPG key was obtained via:

```
# curl -o /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/GPG-KEY-ServicePackforProLiant http://downloads.linux.hpe.com/SDR/repo/spp/GPG-KEY-spp
```

The components were installed via:

```
# yum --enablerepo=spp install hpdiags hp-health hpsmh ssacli
```

The port was opened on CentOS 7's firewall via:

```
# firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=public --add-rich-rule='
  rule family="ipv4"
  source address="172.33.12.4/32"
  port protocol="tcp" port="2381" accept'
# firewall-cmd --reload
```

(172.33.12.4 is an internal management station where I'm logging in to the SMH via web browser.)

SMH was configured to work in this environment via:

```
# /opt/hp/hpsmh/sbin/smhconfig --port2301=false
# /opt/hp/hpsmh/sbin/smhconfig --user-group=smhadmins
```

Connecting to https://smhserver:2381 works great and I can log in, so the user-group and firewall rules are all good.

Once logged in, I saw the above incomplete info. A bit of Google led me to this discussion: https://community.hpe.com/t5/Server-Management-Systems/System-Management-Homepage-is-blank/td-p/4616818. Based on that info (even though it was for Windows), I installed and configured the SNMP agents:

```
# yum --enablerepo=spp install hp-snmp-agents
# /sbin/hpsnmpconfig
# service hpsmhd restart
```

(I set up the Read/Write community and Read Only community, but I left management station IPs blank.)

What should I try next?

Comment: Restart the snmpd daemon.

Comment: Did that and more just now-- went for a whole server restart. No change. I'm about to embark on a full uninstall/reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

Found it! The package "hp-smh-templates" is more than just a suggestion, **it's a requirement**.

```
# yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo=spp install hp-smh-templates
# service hpsmhd restart
```

Here's how things look now. I think that the "Management Processor" "none" and "Data Source" (blank) are a bit odd so there may be more work to do.

[image]

Comment: This also served as a good reference: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=55506

Comment: [Yeah, you were missing that part](https://serverfault.com/a/565224/13325).