# mcelog and HP BL460 : understand DIMM error

Tags: monitoring, hp, hp-proliant, mcelog

As title says, on one of my BL460, i have a RedHat installed, and a recurrent message in /var/log/messages from mcelog deamon, telling me:

mcelog: Corrected memory errors on page 61a5dd000 exceed threshold 10 in 24h: 10 in 24h
mcelog: Location SOCKET:1 CHANNEL:1 DIMM:0 []
mcelog: Offlining page 61a5dd000
mcelog: Offlining page 61a5dd000 failed: Input/output error

I have two questions:

1. Is the message is "normal", i mean the system see errors, correct them, and then after all corrections I shouldn't have those errors anymore in /var/log/messages ? (even tho it means some dimm module has some errors)
2. I try to locate the DIMM module, but i don't find it.
   I located the PROC 1 of BL, and the CHANNEL 1 pair. But in BL460, DIMM or listed as 1 to 6 . I assumed DIMM:0 was the physical DIMM 1, but after removing it but the message still appears in /var/log/messages. (then I removed 1 and 2 after to check because both are CHANNEL1, but still same)
   How can I understand which physical DIMM it is ?

Thank you :)

Comment: Can you install the HP management agents?

Answer (score 0):

This is a case where you should have the HPE management agents installed. I don't use mcelog on proper HPE server equipment.

See: [HP ProLiant DL380e Gen8 server - SPP use](https://serverfault.com/questions/565221/hp-proliant-dl380e-gen8-server-spp-use/565224#565224)

For RHEL/CentOS, these drivers manage system health and reporting to the OS. Granted, you can also get this information directly from the ILO.

Example output:

```
hpasmcli> show dimm
DIMM Configuration
------------------
Processor #:                     1
Module #:                     1
Present:                      Yes
Form Factor:                  9h
Memory Type:                  DDR3(18h)
Size:                         8192 MB
Speed:                        1866 MHz
Supports Lock Step:           No
Configured for Lock Step:     No
Status:                       Ok

Processor #:                     1
Module #:                     4
Present:                      Yes
Form Factor:                  9h
Memory Type:                  DDR3(18h)
Size:                         8192 MB
Speed:                        1866 MHz
Supports Lock Step:           No
Configured for Lock Step:     No
Status:                       Ok
```

Or via ILO...

[image]