# Is an HP Proliant 350e Gen8 server appropriate for Primevera and Sage applications?

Tags: sql-server-2008, hard-drive, sql, hp, hp-proliant

I want to buy a server to accommodate both the Primevera and Sage applications? Would a HP Proliant 350e Gen8 do? Are there any concerns about this platform?

Comment: Shouldn't be saying this but they're getting rid of the DL380e model in the Gen9 range and moving it down to being a 1xx series box - they've not sold well (the DL380p remains the best selling server of all makes/models).

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no...

The server is capable of running the applications and Windows Server 2008/2012 from a CPU and RAM perspective. However, there is a fairly large limitation in the storage array controller for that particular server line. HP ProLiant servers are available in ["e" (essential) and "p" (performance)](https://serverfault.com/questions/568313/poor-sql-performance-on-hp-proliant-ml310e-gen8-v2-with-raid10/568388#568388) variants. If you can afford the initial cost, the "p" models are always a better choice.

The storage problems with the "essential" models require better RAID controllers and additional cache in order to function at a reasonable level. At that point, it makes sense to buy the better server.

[image]