# Trouble installing CentOS 7 on HP Dl120 Gen9 using RAID controller

Tags: centos, raid, hp, centos7, hardware-raid

I have HP Dl120 Gen9 to install CentOS 7, I have tried to install CentOS 7 on Raid 0 (not too risky for test server) but apparently I had a problem booting it.

Next thing I did is to create a new array with Raid 5 (2.73 TB Usable in total of 4.00 TB). But still, when I installed CentOS 7, is still doesn't boot up.

How come it doesn't boot CentOS, thanks in advance for any tips.

Edit * There is no error message or any log that I could show off!

Comment: raid controller recognized in centoa?

Comment: Did you install CentOS from a USB key?

Comment: @yagmoth555 It did once, then it didnt. (b140i), then I tried to create volumes manually by selecting all the disks. Should I remove the array and try to create via software raid?

Comment: @ewwhite I have tried both from USB and DVD

Comment: The answer is never R5 - discount it - it's been 'dead' for over half a decade, amateurs use it - use R1/10 or R6/60 only.

Comment: You haven't provided enough details. You're just saying it doesn't boot up. That's not enough information for anyone to help you fix your problem. Tell us exactly what you did and what happens.. error messages!

Comment: The best raid configuration is what works for you. What are you're requirements?

Comment: @RyanBabchishin Thank you for answering, but unfortunately I don't get any error message or something to show off. It installs the system without any problem, asks for a reboot to use Centos, as soon as I reboot, it doesn't boot up. I specifically select CentOS from boot menu, but it redirects me to boot menu as soon as I hit enter button.

Comment: @RyanBabchishin I am going to use it for video streaming -which I am thinking to use R10 but to test all combinatons first I have to install OS to execute my benchmarks for all specs :-)

Comment: @A.MesutKonuklar Can you try a different distro? With a newer kernel?

Comment: @RyanBabchishin I am on it, will notice the result, thanks

Comment: @A.MesutKonuklar http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201509-19593/

Comment: @RyanBabchishin 14.04 installed without any problem, pretty interesting. In the mean time I also found http://serverfault.com/questions/721523/install-centos-7-on-hp-dl120-gen9-server-with-b140i-raid-controller which I couldn't before opening this topic. I hope this will fix my issue too!

Comment: @A.MesutKonuklar Wow nice. Things are looking up. FYI, RAID 10 is fast and redundant. It's a good choice if you need redundancy. You may need a large stripe size to get fast large sequential file transfers. Video stuff may be kind of the same depending on what you're doing. Consider that in your benchmarks.

Comment: The discussion about which RAID config you should use and your problems booting are 2 seperate issues. But since you've not told us if this is hardware or software RAID we can't guess at the answer. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try a different Linux distribution**

**Ubuntu 14.04.1 was verified working** by Ubuntu on your server. There are some exceptions/details involved (drivers to install):

http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201509-19593/

As far as RAID levels are concerned, go with what works for you. I'm sure you have performance requirements or price/hardware limitations. I've mentioned that RAID 10 is not a bad idea in the comments, but really you could do RAID 0 or RAID 5 for all I care as long as it meets your needs.