# SSA configured RAID1 array not visible in CentOS7 installation

Tags: raid, centos7, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have a ProLiant ML30 Gen9 server with an hardware raid adapter that I can configure using HP's "Smart Storage Administrator" (SSA) tool. I have defined my two 1TB drives to be in a RAID1 setup as a logical drive and enabled the primary boot on them.

However, if I start the CentOS7 installation, I can still select `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` as installation medium, where I would expect only one (logical, mirrored, raid) drive.

**update** It is a Smart Array B140i. I have tried to load drivers, but they either lock up the install, cannot be loaded or do not return the array in the install. I spent an hour with HP support (which could only tell me to reset to defaults and get me links I already found).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which RAID controller is in the system?

Comment: @ewwhite it is a Dynamic Smart Array B140i

Answer (score 0):

For the Dynamic Smart Array Controller, you will need to *slipstream* the proper driver disk into the CentOS 7 installer.

Please see [page 10 of the installation manual](http://h20566.www2.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=c04441385) for the RAID controller.

> A device driver is required for the operating system to communicate
>   with the disk drive controller. For more information on supported
>   operating systems, see the product page for the appropriate controller
>   on the Hewlett Packard Enterprise website
>   (http://www.hpe.com/info/dynamicsa).

Comment: I really cannot find anything useful on the HP site. I tried the info from this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/721523/install-centos-7-on-hp-dl120-gen9-server-with-b140i-raid-controller But that didn't work, it says it cannot find a driver on the disk.

Comment: As said in the update of my question, I tried quite some drivers, all of them don't work.