# CentOS 6.5 with HP ProLiant DL360e Gen8

Tags: centos, raid, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

I have a chance to install a new HP ProLiant DL360e Gen8 server. There are three hard drives.

How do I configure RAID 1 on this type of server.

Will RAID already be configured so that it will look like one hard drive while installing CentOS, or should I manually create RAID while partitioning?

If I partition like that, will I do RAID 1 using 2 disks, then what about hard disk 3? How to use further for taking backup's in that HDD?

Comment: Ouch, good luck with that.  You're in pretty bad shape - [see the answer here for the ugly details about that model of server](http://serverfault.com/a/448373/118258).

Answer (score 5):

This server uses a binary RAID driver, so you may need to use a driver disk to install CentOS on the system if you want hardware RAID. Otherwise the disks will not be recognized by the installer. You can also use software RAID.

Red Hat explains this in the following article: https://access.redhat.com/site/articles/118133

*This mode requires a closed source driver that is not shipped or supported by Red Hat. In order to install RHEL on these systems without the closed source driver and RAID support, the Software RAID mode must either be disabled (B320i controller) or switched to SATA AHCI support mode (B120i SATA controller).*

```
For systems with the B320i SAS controller:
1. Boot the server into System Options
2. Navigate to HP Smart Array B320i Raid Configuration
3. Change to DISABLED
```

This is also documented here: [HP DL380e Linux not seeing drive array for installation](https://serverfault.com/questions/448368/hp-dl380e-linux-not-seeing-drive-array-for-installation/448373#448373)