# CentOS 6.5 not booting after installation on Hp ML310e Gen8

Tags: centos, hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array, fakeraid

I have experience with Installation and configuration of Windows Server system. I am trying to install CentOS 6.5 on the above mentioned HP box and the installation process goes on without a hitch. Once it is done and reboots, it does not see the boot partitions. When I attempt to re-do the install I notice the earlier partitions are there but the mount points are missing. I have also tried Fedora 18 on the same box.

This is a machine that used to run Windows 2008 without any issues. (HDDs were reformated for a clean start)

I would also like to mention that even if I configure RAID using HP's Smart Array tool on Centos during installation it still shows the two separate physical drives. I removed all other hard drives so that there is only one to work with but still the same result.

How can I get centOS or Fedora installed onto HP Ml310e Gen8?

Answer (score 2):

Please see the links and answers at: [HP DL380e Linux not seeing drive array for installation](https://serverfault.com/questions/448368/hp-dl380e-linux-not-seeing-drive-array-for-installation/448373#448373)

You're running into a RAID controller and drive incompatibility of this server. The Dynamic Smart Array RAID controller installed on the machine requires a binary-driver that needs to be slipstreamed into your installation.

There's a driver-disk available for this.

Answer (score 0):

Little bit late, but I had same problem while installing centos 7. My HP ProLiant machine has two HP Smart Array and I install the boot partition on one of them and my machine configured to boot with other. So I changed the primary boot drive to the one that boot partition was installed on (**to change primary boot drive in smary array configuration menu which you can open it with pressing f8 while smart array initalization during boot**). After I restarted the machine, it could be boot and grub menu was opened.