# hp proliant ml350 g4 broken scsi port?

Tags: hp-proliant

I jsut got an hp proliant ml350 g4 from my nephew. He didnt know what to do with it and he didnt got it working. Now im trying to get it to work.
what ive done:
1 I've created a logical drive. raid 5.
2 I downloaded centOS. It's centOS 7 DVD ISO
3 I tried to boot it from an external hdd.

edit: this is the question:
Now it gives me the error:
Attempting boot from CD-ROM
Attempting boot from hard drive (c:)

Non-System disk or disk error.
Replace and strike any key when ready.


<strike>I guess one of my hdd's is broken due to the fact of the error and the fact that one of the hdd's doesnt give any light sign like the other 5 do.</strike>
update: I think it may be the port it's in.
upate 2: after some research I found that the problem may lie with the scsi simplex backplate. When its trying to boot every one one them gives a green light except one.

Answer (score 1):

This server is from 2004 and is not supported in any way by CentOS 7. The RAID controller for that platform has been dropped from Red Hat kernels.

See: [CentOS 7 x64 and HP Proliant DL360 G5 SCSI Controller compatibility](https://serverfault.com/questions/611182/centos-7-x64-and-hp-proliant-dl360-g5-scsi-controller-compatibility/611210#611210)

Comment: it doesnt even reach the fase where it wants to boot from the external hard drive. So i guess a drive is broken. Can I start the server with 5 drives?
Btw: im a total server noob. Its my first one ever and i have 0 experience with it.

Comment: Update. Not the hdd is broken. I think its the port. I just changed 2 hdd's and the one in port 4 doesnt seem to give the database icon. But in another port it does light up the database sign.