# Hard drive isn't reconized when installing OS on proliant server

Tags: windows, centos, raid, hp-proliant

I have a HP Proliant server model DL380 G5. 1 SAS hard drive 72GB and 1 SATA 300gb. Also i have a hp smart array p400 bbwc. (power of bbwc is low also has a warning sign)

I'm trying to install an operating system on this server but when i try to install CentOS via DVD it won't show the hard drive's.

I tried to configure the hard drive's as logical drive's via the hp rom configuration utility. There i have 3 options to create/view/delete array's.

When i tried to install windows server 2012 standard with gui it shows the hard drives but when i try to install the os on the server it says:
"We couldn't create a new partition or locate an existing one".

Is there something i am missing? Why won't CentOS detect my hard drives?

Comment: This usually happens when you need to add a driver so you can get all your drives into it. or just need to delete the existent partitions so it can show up.

Comment: Did you create your logical drive first?

Answer (score 0):

You're not first person who have problems with this controller, see this [forum post](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=47011). Or you could check [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/611182/centos-7-x64-and-hp-proliant-dl360-g5-scsi-controller-compatibility), it should solve your problem.